# How to find duplicate values for a key in Map

Tags: java

I have a scenario where I need to read a JSON file and check duplicate entry for a key (`MEMBER_ID`) and if duplicate exist then I need to fetch last entry (Last updated details of member ) and add to final list. e.g in below json, for `MEMBER_ID=123` there are 2 entries and one with `LASTNAME` as `VSDWRVFFZA` should be added to final list. I tried couple of ways to do filtering but couldn't come up with final solution. Can someone please suggest how can I proceed with this?

I have written logic as :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
...
...

`if (file.exists() && file.length() != 0) {
            jsonValue = objectMapper.readValue(file, List.class);
            jsonValue.forEach(value -> {
                try {
                    populateAndMapJSON(value);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });`...
...


        private void populateAndMapJSON(Map<String, Object> value) throws IOException {

        if ((value.containsKey(FIRST_NAME) || value.containsKey(LAST_NAME)) {

// NOT SURE HOW TO PUT FILTER HERE FOR GIVEN SCENARIO

            finalList.add(value);
...
..
```

// JSON that I am using:

```
{
    "MEMBER_ID": "123",
    "LASTNAME": " fgjksnc",
    "BIRTH_DATE": "1905-12-29",
    "FIRSTNAME": "abcdf",
}, {
    "MEMBER_ID": "09876",
    "M": "abc",
    "N": "def"
}, {
    "MEMBER_ID": "123",
    "LASTNAME": "VSDWRVFFZA",
    "BIRTH_DATE": "1905-12-20",
    "FIRSTNAME": "UFZCY LGNF",
}
```

Comment: "_Last updated details of member_" is known how ? You have [`Map.outIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) or simply [`Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) that return the previous values if any. With those two, you should be able to insert the values based on your requirements (that I don't fully understand so I let you do it). Or if you want to set multiple values for a same key, check [`MultiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Looks like you've a JSON array here

Comment: how you came up on duplicate keys on map ? maybe you should consider to use another structure?

Comment: Could you clarify the following?

1. Are you handling a JSON Array?
2. What key do you want to check for uniqueness?

Comment: Yes. Its Json array and I am using objectMapper.readValue(file, List.class) to get jsonValue  which is of type List<Map<String, Object>>.

Comment: First, the json is incorrect, `"FIRSTNAME": "abcdf",}` is not valid because of the comma. Seconds, you didn't specify how you know that a JSONObject is the _"Last updated details of member"_. Is the array ordered by that value? Please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you are not able to do. See [ask] and how to provde a [mcve]. And of course, you need to specifiy the input/output expected. What API you are using to read the JSON, ...

Answer (score 0):

Using the stream API, you can

- group by the MEMBER_ID (resulting in a list of matches by id), and then
- reduce multiple matches by using the last one

Code:

```
Set<Map<String, Object>> uniqueByLast = finalList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("MEMBER_ID"))) // group by id
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .reduce((first, second) -> second)) // find last, if multiple entries
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

As a result, you get a set of all unique object maps.